How to validate strings to compile time?
I am trying to make the following code work:
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <print>

template<char Specifier>
struct ParseSpecifier;

template<>
struct ParseSpecifier<'s'>
{
    static void parse()
    {
        std::println("string");
    }
};

template<>
struct ParseSpecifier<'i'>
{
    static void parse()
    {
        std::println("integer");
    }
};

template<std::size_t Index>
void parse_format(const std::string_view format)
{
    if (Index == format.size())
        return;
    
    ParseSpecifier<format[Index]>::parse();
    parse_format<Index + 1>(format);
}

int main()
{
    parse_format<0>("iiisss");
}

I know there exist libraries (like fmt) that can compile time validate format strings so this must be possible somehow. I should note, the ultimate goal is not to print "string" and "integer", but rather to create a std::tuple based on the i and ss in the provided string. The string will always be known at compile time.
I am starting small as I am only just learning template metaprogramming. How can I make code like this work? I understand format is not constexpr as function parameters cannot be. Additionally, std::string_view cannot be a template parameter. If I use template<char... Chars> then I have to call the function like parse_format<0, 'i', 's', 's', 'i', 's'>();, which is horrible.
Is there any way I can get my attempted code to function? If not, what is the best strategy for compile time validation of strings?
Important note, the final function will be called with one compile time known parameter and one real time parameter (much like fmt::format).
Easy edit: https://godbolt.org/z/s8eoYarja

I see that an accepted answer has been provided but I'm failing to understand your goal.  What I see is expected to output "integer" or "string" which is not a compile-time behavior. Can you clarify what your expecting? A guess: parse_format should static_assert if a compile-time provided string is ill-formed.

@Oersted, As I mentioned in the description, "the ultimate goal is not to print "string" and "integer", but rather to create a std::tuple based on the i and s in the provided string. The string will always be known at compile time." As for my expectation: I could not format the string as the compiler had no way of knowing format was known at compile time, and that function could not be made consteval as it needed to be run at runtime. I needed a way to parse format at compile time. The accepted answer did that perfectly.

OK, I get it now. IMHO, a pseudo-code illustrating the desired API/behavior (with tuple) would have made your intent clearer but if you have your answer anyway, it's great.

The way libfmt (and std::format) do it is by passing a custom class instead of std::string_view, with a consteval constructor accepting a string. Said constructor runs at compile-time and can e.g. throw (or do something else) to cause a compile-time error.
But this approach doesn't let you do this:

create a std::tuple based on the i and ss in the provided string

This requires passing the string as a template parameter:
template <std::size_t N>
struct ConstString
{
    char value[N]{};

    constexpr ConstString() {}
    constexpr ConstString(const char (&str)[N])
    {
        std::copy_n(str, N, value);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr std::string_view view() const
    {
        return std::string_view(value, value + N - 1);
    }
};

template <ConstString S>
void foo();

int main()
{
    foo<"blah">();
}

Or with a slightly different call syntax:
template <ConstString>
struct ConstStringTag {};

template <ConstString S>
[[nodiscard]] ConstStringTag<S> constexpr operator""_c() {return {};}

template <ConstString S>
void foo(ConstStringTag<S>);

int main()
{
    foo("blah"_c);
}


"The way libfmt (and std::format) do it is by passing a custom class ... with a consteval constructor. I saw std::format was using std::format_string<Args...>." Unfortunately, I am nowhere near the level required to read standard library implementations for even benign things.

@Eshy I'm afraid, to describe and explain Standard Library code in words  it requires a work comparable to second coming of Vandevoorde's book.
